# Strictly server-side processing (no web browser interaction):  is Java or PHP better for this scenario?

Tags: java, php, server-side, websocket

Here's the situation:

I currently have a web application that uses PHP to serve HTML/CSS/JS and that talks to a MySQL DB. Completely vanilla and common. The PHP is a mixture of presentation logic (HTML generation, etc) and business logic (the app uses Ajax extensively to make requests for data or to tell the server to make changes to something).

As part of a redesign of this system I am removing all of the presentation logic from the PHP. Instead, I will be using [Ext JS 4](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/) (a javascript-based windowing toolkit / app) connected to a [web socket gateway](http://kaazing.com) (a COMET/AJAX replacement that allows bi-directional communication) on the server. Let's wave a magic wand for a minute and forget about how the Ext JS 4 gets delivered to the browser and how it talks to the web socket gateway.

What we are left with is a web socket gateway (written in Java and running persistently listening on a specific port for web socket connections) and some business logic / DB interaction currently written in PHP.

At this point, I see one of two options:

1. Keep the business logic / DB interaction in the PHP and execute it by calling either PHP from the command line or by having the PHP / Apache listen on a different port only for communications from the web socket gateway.
2. Write a new Java or C++ application that will be persistent and listen on a specific port for communications from the web socket gateway. The business logic / DB integration is re-written in Java or C++ code and is part of this application.

Would re-writing in Java or C++ give better performance than calling PHP over and over? (The PHP code is pretty cleanly written: object-oriented using packages like CodeIgniter and Doctrine).

Would the performance benefits outweigh the hassle of re-writing all the business logic? Obviously dependent on many factors such as quantity of code but what is your gut feeling?

In case it might influence your thinking / feedback, you should know that the web socket gateway (Kaazing) supports JMS, Stomp, AMQP, XMPP, or something custom you build yourself.

Let me know if there is any other info I can provide to help you with your answers.

Thanks!

Comment: Found this in my searches. Not sure if it is useful / relevant: http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32q/benchmark.php?test=all&lang=java&lang2=php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know a lot of the solutions I mention here are "ugly" but you sound like a person who's looking to get results and refactor, so I hope it's okay.

Do it the easy way (PHP if I understood correctly) first. Then run a realistic stress test. Since you're making PHP calls, just create a realistic sequence (log in, change this, do that, log out) and run as many as you think is realistic. 100? 10000? It depends on how stressed you expect this thing to be and still preform.

That step is **easier** than it sounds. Don't think "ultimate test framework", think 20 line python script that runs as many threads as you want executing a few lines that will keep your application busy. If it takes you more than 40 minutes, stop and simplify. The hour you spend will be worth it.

If CPU hits 100 or you run out of some resource then perhaps it's time for a rewrite, or you can probably **guess what's taking the longest** and write it in C. If you do use C/C++ and you're not 100% comfortable with it, avoid a major rewrite, since it's a dangerous language with lots of opportunities for introducing bugs. Maybe even call compiled code from the PHP you have **if that suits your application**.

I've written server-side HTML-generating C code once. It's not exactly the right tool for the job. PHP may be hackish but it gets the job done fast. I would avoid optimization unless/until it is *actually needed*.

Good luck, don't forget to tell us how it goes!

**Edit:** If you do go for a mixed-language solution, don't forget to clean it up after! Standardize what you do fast and what you do in PHP, do it in a common format, maybe write up a short readme. Again, those fifteen minutes will save you, or the next person, a few days and many hairs.

Answer (score 2):

Writing in a compiled language (Java or C++, in your examples) would almost certainly give better performance than an interpreted language like PHP.  The performance benefits almost certainly would not outweigh the hassle of rewriting all of the code.

Comment: @Paul - Java is also an interpreted language! But I agree in many tasks C++ and Java are faster than PHP, as evidenced by publicly available benchmarks.

Comment: @Perception: Java is not an interpreted language.  Java is compiled to bytecode; bytecodes can be interpreted, but they can also be JIT'ed.  However, that's just bytecodes; Java itself is compiled.

Comment: @Paul - ok so Java is a compiled and interpreted language. But in most cases the executable is being 'interpreted' right? This is true even when you use JIT (which is not a standard btw) - some JIT implementations precompile all the way to machine code, alot of them just do cache-ahead. But regardless of how you want to split those hairs C++ is statically compiled and Java is not.

Comment: @Perception: You're missing my point.  Java as a language is compiled to bytecode.  Always.  Bytecode can be interpreted or JIT compiled, but bytecode is not Java.

Comment: @Paul. You're missing my point. It doesn't matter how many intermediary forms the Java source code goes through, when in the end it gets interpreted by a virtual machine.

Comment: @Perception: and you're missing my point; if I take C code, compile it, then run it through an interpreter, does that make it interpreted code?  Of course it doesn't.  You're misunderstanding the meaning of the word "compile".  To compile code does not have ANY association with whether or not the result gets interpreted; compilation is a specific process that involves several steps, none of which are about the execution of the code.

Comment: @Paul: Yes, if you compiled C code and ran it through a mythical interpreter, the interpreted process would be referred to as ... wait for it ... interpretation! See how that works? Wow!

Comment: @PaulSonier let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/992/discussion-between-perception-and-paul-sonier)

Answer (score 1):

- If your business logic has high processing costs, Java or C++ will give you a much better performance.

  If you are simply fetching some results from a DB, do not expect any great performance gains.
- I would do some prototyping/testing to identify the performance bottleneck.
- My opinion is that PHP is too slow for processing HUGE datasets if you have many 100,000s of objects to analyse C++ rocks and Java benefits from the HotSpot JIT performance optimizer.

  The HotSpot effect is very specific to doing number crunching in Java. You really can see the JRE is pushing the accelerator, ironing out detected bottlenecks. In some rare cases HotSpot JIT optimised Java can be even faster than C.

  In some also very rare cases HotSpot performance voodooism can make your code slower!
- Have you ever thought of turning a PHP application into a faster Java or C++ app?

  Maybe the HipHop php2cpp compiler is all you want: 
  https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/

  Quercus is a php4java runtime which can help you migrate more cheaply to Java.
  http://quercus.caucho.com/
- Quite interesting was Joshua Bloch's talk about "Performance Anxiety" last year.
  http://www.wiki.jvmlangsummit.com/images/1/1d/PerformanceAnxiety2010.pdf

  http://parleys.com/#st=5&id=2103 (32min video)